# Choosing berries

Tags: combinatorics

You have 2 blue berries, 2 red berries and 2 black berries

In how many ways can you pick 2 berries?

My work:

you can choose two red berries or you can choose two blackberries or you can choose two blueberries or you can choose 1 blue and 1 red berry or you can choose 1 black and 1 blue berries or you can choose one black and one redd berrie

Extra condition:
Order don't matter and berries identifies only by colour

HEnce:
$ \binom{2}{2} + \binom{2}{2} + \binom{2}{2} + \binom{2}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1}+ \binom{2}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1}+ \binom{2}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1}$=15

Comment: What constitutes a choice?  I'd have thought that  two berries of a given type were indistinguishable, so I'd have said there were $3$ "mixed" selections and $3$ "pure"  (one berry type) selection for a total of $6$.  Of course, this would not be correct if you say all the berries are distinct, but in that case the answer is, simply, $\binom 62=15$, as you say.

Comment: My friend came up with this question and we are having argument whether the answer is 9 or 15. My logic of saying it is 15 is because there are four ways to make a pair.

Comment: Just out of interest, how on earth did you come up with $9$?

Comment: I see no argument for $9$.  As I say, I believe the best answer to be $6$.

Comment: You have three berries to choose from and two spots, so 3 x3 . First one three choices and second also three

Comment: Yeah, but then you would be counting Red-Black and Black-Red as distinct choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple application of the "stars and bars" method.

You are asked to choose $2$ objects (two berries) from a choice of $3$ (three types of berries), where repitition is allowed but order does not matter. Hence we have

$$H^3_2 = C^{3+2-1}_2=C^4_2=6$$

---

**Edit:**

$H$ is probably not commonly seen, so I shall explain below.

In general, you are asked to choose $r$ objects from a set of $n$ objects. Repetition may or may not be allowed, and Order may or may not matter.

$\color{red}{\text{Repetition not allowed, }}\color{red}{\text{Order does not matter}}$

$$C^n_r = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

$\color{green}{\text{Repetition allowed, }}\color{red}{\text{Order does not matter}}$

$$H^n_r = C^{n+r-1}_r = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$$

$\color{red}{\text{Repetition not allowed, }}\color{green}{\text{Order matters}}$

$$P^n_r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$

$\color{green}{\text{Repetition allowed, }}\color{green}{\text{Order matters}}$

$$n^r$$

Comment: Summarised in my edit